# Nginx keep serving domain that is not in the configuration

Tags: nginx

I've have a domain example.ovh and another domain, say vps-example.ovh.

I've configured nginx in the way that only https://example.ovh is served.

In my example, both two domains are still served (vps-example.ovh and example.ovh) although vps-example.ovh is not part of the configuration

```
server {
        listen   80;
        # listen [::]:80 default_server deferred;
        # return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        return 444;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name test.ovh;
    include snippets/self-signed.conf;
    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    location / {
        proxy_pass         http://localhost:5000;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If Nginx cannot match a `server_name` it will use the default server. If you want Nginx to do something else, you need to define a "catch all" server block.

You could add a `listen 443 ssl default_server;` statement to your first `server` block, but it will need a certificate. You can probably include the SSL configuration in the outer block, so that it will be inherited by both `server` blocks.

```
include snippets/self-signed.conf;
include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen 443 ssl default_server;
    return 444;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name example.com;
    ...
```

The certificate may not be valid, and the browser may generate a warning. But the main site will no longer be accessible using any name not listed in the `server_name` directive.